# Identity Server 3 - Asp.net Site

Tags: c#, asp.net, identityserver3

I'm working with identity Server.
Created POC using Asp.net website and Identity Server3.
We successfully login into identity server.
**Issue :**  When we login successfully after display page like following screen shot.

[image: Permission Issue]

Following is my code.

[image: Startup File]

Comment: Welcome to [SO]. Please paste the code into the question. Do not use an image of the code, as this is harder to read. Use the [edit] button to update the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove the 
`LoginPath = new PathString("/identity/permissions)` line from your cookie middleware.

The `/permissions` endpoint shows you client applications that the user has authorized to use their data. It is not involved in the login process.

Comment: I'm using "ASP.net website" as Application. When i remove LoginPath that time i cann't redirect to Identity Server.

Comment: But the page you are seeing is because of the above. If it doesn't work with that removed then suggests further issues. If the request isn't making it to IdentityServer, you'll need to look at either the katana logging for your client application or what's going on in the redirect to identity provider notification.

Comment: Finally, i have done without using LoginPath display identity server login page. but after login we have issue for redirect to application. is there any log sample code for loggin , i am not able to installing serilog in my appllication. kindly suggest any logger name. Thanks